# updating record in android programming

Tags: android

I am writing a program to display the details of students' record in android. I am using a existing database and getting the data from it. Here I need to update the status as confirmed.
I have created a confirmation button which on pressing will update the status as confirmed. Here on pressing the button my code shows no error but the value is not updated in the database. For information I am using sqlitebrowser as my database.

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    //contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.STATUS,"CONFIRMED");
    StudentDetails = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("", null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    //status.setText("CONFIRMED");
     //mDbHelper.close();
    values.put("Status", "Confrimed");

    StudentDetails.insert("Student","", values);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Status upadated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    StudentDetails.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can get results back from insert/update statements (rows affected/id). Can you check if the results are ok?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you've supplied `""` as the argument to `path` for `openDatabase()`. Unless you're calling this on a member that will open the appropriate database, I believe this wouldn't open a valid database, and thus I wouldn't be surprised if a row didn't get written to the table you were trying to modify. Perhaps **try supplying a database file name** instead of a blank string and see if that works.

Also, if you're not implementing `SQLiteOpenHelper` in your own class as outlined in [Saving Data in SQL Databases](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html), I would suggest trying that instead of accessing the database in another way, if it isn't too much trouble. I've just made an app using this method, and I have no problems.

Nonetheless, I would assign a `long` to the output value of the `insert` function, and set a debug point or write its value of the console. If the value is -1, the method didn't assign a row to the table (possibly because of database constraints - perhaps check that you're satisfying them in terms of the values supplied in the `Bundle`).

The value returned from `insert` will be -1 if an error occurred, as outlined in the docs for [`insert(String table, String nullColumnHack, ContentValues values)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)).

Answer (score 0):

You should use StudentDetails.update("Student","", values);